# Disable hook/function loaded by a plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

A wordpress plugin I'm using is loading the following code (which disables my add to cart button), and I need this code removed so that my add to cart button won't get disabled by the plugin.

I need a way to do this without editing the actual plugin files.

Here is the code responsible (the code that I need to remove):

```
// Remove default variable product add to cart
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_variable_product_add_to_cart');
function remove_variable_product_add_to_cart()
{
    remove_action('woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30);
}
```

I tried adding the following to functions.php (but it didn't work)

```
remove_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_variable_product_add_to_cart');
```

I also tried adding a priority:

```
remove_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_variable_product_add_to_cart', 1);
```

Why is this not working, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the `plugins_loaded` hook from the theme, because this hook has already been executed before running the theme.

There are two ways to remove this hook:

1. Develop a plugin and install it and put the code inside it.
2. Go to the following path: **RECOMMENDED**

> public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/

And create an `index.php` file and put your code in it.

**NOTE**

`mu_plugins` means **[Must Use Plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/)**. WordPress first executes its core files, then files inside the `mu_plugins` and `plugins` directory, and finally the theme. If you do not have the `mu_plugins` folder in the `wp-content` directory, create one and create your file inside it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I see that the "must use plugins" executes before normal plugins. Will this be a problem? Or will it work that way?

Comment: Please read [this section](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/#features)